# Can we add items from each int array that have the same index in Java?

Tags: java

For example, if I want to achieve something like

```
int[] a  = [1,2];
int[] b = [3,4];
```

I want to get a new int[] which is `[4,6]`, is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: You probably *could* do it declaratively with streams... but it's only about 4 lines of code to do it with a simple "create array, loop to populate it"...

Comment: @jhyot how does the linked question apply here?

Comment: @QBrute admittedly it's a bit of a stretch, but presumably the asker wanted some other solution than iterating over the array, and the closest would be "zipping" streams of two lists (which are like arrays) together. The linked question does combine two lists into a map instead of a new list/array.

Comment: @jhyot, you got me

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new array from a fixed index of many arrays, you could use something like this:

```
    static int[] getAnArrayFromSameIndex(int index, int[]... arrays) {
        int[] result = new int[arrays.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            if(index > arrays[i].length) {
                return result; 
            }else {
            
                for(int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                    result[j] = arrays[j][index];
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

this will return a new array from a index of n number of given arrays.